# How to use locale files?

Tags: magento-1.7, locale

> /var/www/app/code/local/Lpf/ModuleUrlBackAfterLogin/controllers/AccountController.php

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addNotice('Your account needs to be approved...');
```

I'm looking for a way to have the above string translated in my french webstore.

I have set that string in `/var/www/app/locale/fr_FR/Mage_Customer.csv`, but the web site keeps displaying the English version.

Comment: have you clear  Cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Magento, translation are managed by the `Mage_Core_Model_Translate` object.

You can call it throught the

- `Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract::__()`
- `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::__()`
- `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::__()`
- `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::__()`

So you can translate a string by calling `$this->__('string to translate');` in blocks, admin controllers, front controllers and helpers.

In a model, you can delegate to any helper by calling `Mage::helper('moduleName/helperName')->__('string to translate');`

If your module does not have a custom helper, delegate it to the core helper `Mage::helper('core')->__('string to translate');`

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass it to a helper: something like

```
getSingleton('customer/session')->addNotice(Mage::helper('core')->__('Your account needs to be approved...'));
```

Only texts passed to a Mage helper's __() method would be translated.

Comment: Good Paras sood